# OpenCV(4.2.0),imwrite() to a subfolder breaks the module; cv2.error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'`'

Tags: python, opencv

I'm practicing with Computer Vision in python  and was trying to resize some images I have stored in a subfolder of where the sript is i used the following code

```
import cv2
import glob

immagini = glob.glob('.\immagini\*.jpg')
print(immagini)

for image in immagini :
    img = cv2.imread(image,0)
    re= cv2.resize(img,(100,100))
    cv2.imshow("*",re)
    cv2.waitKey(500)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.imwrite("resized_"+image , re)
```

,it seems to find the image and succefully resize them however it doesn't save them;therefore i applied this changes to access the full path

```
import cv2
import glob
import os

path =r'C:\Users\...\ComputerVision\immagini'
immagini = glob.glob('.\immagini\*.jpg')
print(immagini)

for image in immagini :
    img = cv2.imread(image,0)
    # print(type(immagini))
    # print(img)
    os.chdir(path)
    re= cv2.resize(img,(100,100))
    cv2.imshow("yo",re)
    cv2.waitKey(500)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.imwrite("resized_"+image , re)
    print(os.listdir(path))
```

and now i get this output with annexed error

```
`'.\\immagini\\galaxy.jpg', '.\\immagini\\kangaroos-rain-australia_71370_990x742.jpg', '.\\
immagini\\Lighthouse.jpg', '.\\immagini\\Moon sinking, sun rising.jpg']
['galaxy.jpg', 'kangaroos-rain-australia_71370_990x742.jpg', 'Lighthouse.jpg', 'Moon sinkin
g, sun rising.jpg']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\script1.py", line 15, in <module>
    re= cv2.resize(img,(100,100))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:40
45: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'`'
```

Can somebody explain me what's going on here? why do i have two prints(the latter is the one i wanted) and how do i correct the error and save my resized files in the right directory?

P.S. This is my first question so please be kind, I found that this kind of error is due to some mispelling in the cv2 module but couldn't find a solution

Comment: The question is very well written, but I think you could improve even more by simplifying the title to tell just what is the question about. Congrats on your first question.

Comment: @FernandoSilveira Hey thanks! Ive found a lot of solution by just typing my error and i figured i would do the same.Do you think i should include part of the error or just my question of saving files in a subfolder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time in your for loop, you change a immagini directory by os.chdir(path), it is no problem with showing image.

Second time in the for loop, the image variable indicates .\immagini\galaxy.jpg which is relative path but the current is now a immagini directory  so the image is pointing an wrong path in which the img variable is already empty.

Finally, If you want to save a resized image at the same directory,
I think you have to split a path and a file name from the image variable in the for loop.

This is a first one:

```
import cv2
import glob
import os

immagini = glob.glob('.\immagini\*.jpg')
#print(immagini)

for image in immagini :
    img = cv2.imread(image,0)
    re= cv2.resize(img,(100,100))
    cv2.imshow("images",re)
    cv2.waitKey(500)
    fname = os.path.basename(image)
    fdir = os.path.dirname(image)
    simage = fdir + os.path.sep +"resized_"+ fname
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.imwrite(simage, re)
```

And second one :

```
import cv2
import glob
import os

path =r'C:\Users\...\ComputerVision\immagini'
immagini = glob.glob('.\immagini\*.jpg')

for image in immagini:
    os.chdir(path)
    fname = os.path.basename(image)
    img = cv2.imread(fname,0)
    # print(type(immagini))
    # print(img)
    #os.chdir(path)
    re= cv2.resize(img,(100,100))
    cv2.imshow("yo",re)
    cv2.waitKey(500)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.imwrite("resized_"+fname , re)
    print(os.listdir(path))
```

I hope i can help you.

Comment: Thanks alot, you explained and i understood why the error was happening and you solved my problem (i used the first solution)